# Rails Installation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install `Rails` on my `MAC` using the following command :

```
gem install rails -v 5.0.0.1
```

It's not installing and this is the blocker I'm receiving in the terminal output :

```
`block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
```

I've been attempting to find what's going on for the past 2 hours and still have no idea.

Edit 1:
My `Ruby` version is 2.3.1

Edit 2:

This is the error I'm getting on the terminal :

```
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
from /Users/jalajpunn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
from /Users/jalajpunn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
from /Users/jalajpunn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
from /Users/jalajpunn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:555:in `<main>'
```

Comment: There's probably more output than that.  Can you provide a few more lines?

Comment: That error message does not mean that there is a "blocker" (there is no such thing) it means that an error occurred in a block (an anonymous function).

Comment: Just updated in relation to both comments